# I am trying to update part of my HTML every second and fetching data from database into that Div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update part of my HTML every second and fetching data from database into that Div but the code is not working. :( Please help. The first section of code is html page where update function is called and ajax call is made on check_status.php and check_status.php fetches the data from php file from database

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reloading testing</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var statusIntervalId = window.setInterval(update, 1000);

function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check_status.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            if (parseInt(data) == 0) {
                $("#status").css({ color: "red" }).text("offline");
            } else {
                $("#status").css({ color: "green" }).text("online");
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Refresh part of the page</h1>
    <div id="status">
    </div>  
</body>
</html>


This is check_status.php

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<?php 
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("manchesterunited", $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players LIMIT 1"));
    mysql_close($con);
    echo $row[0]; ?>
</body>
</html>
    }
```

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not very helpful. What is failing? What have you tried?

Comment: Did you look on network traffic whether the AJAX request correctly sent to the server? The server correctly responded? Did you have some error in console? Try to be clearer in your question, please. You also missed the protocol in your `script` tag for jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error related to parentheses. Try this:

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check_status.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            if (parseInt(data) == 0) {
                $("#status").css({ color: "red" }).text("offline");
            } else {
                $("#status").css({ color: "green" }).text("online");
            }
        }
    });    // properly end the ajax() invocation
}
```

You should be able to fix syntax problems yourself with the help of errors reported on the javascript console.